# removing duplicate words of specific type within a column in r dataframe

Tags: r, string, nlp

I have a column State as shown below

```
            State
            Arizona, Arizona, Arizona, Arizona, 
            Arizona, Arizona, Arizona, California Carmel Beach, California LBC, California Napa, Arizona
            Virginia, Virginia, Virginia
            .
            .
            .
```

I want to remove all duplicate words of specific type retain one unique word in this case I want to remove only duplicate Arizona words and Virginia Words and the final dataset should look like this below

```
            Result
            Arizona
            Arizona, California Carmel Beach, California LBC, California Napa
            Virginia
            .
            .
            .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create a test data vector
testin <- c(
"Arizona, Arizona, Arizona, Arizona, ", 
"Arizona, Arizona, Arizona, California Carmel Beach, California LBC, California Napa, Arizona", 
"Virginia, Virginia, Virginia"
)

# The names to remove if duplicated
kickDuplicates <- c("Arizona", "Virginia")


# create a list of vectors of place names
broken <- strsplit(testin, ",\\s*")

# paste each broken vector of place names back together
# .......kicking out duplicated instances of the chosen names
testout <- sapply(broken, FUN = function(x)  paste(x[!duplicated(x) | !x %in% kickDuplicates ], collapse = ", "))

# see what we did 
testout
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
trimmed <- gsub('^\\s*','',state)
trimmed <- gsub('\\s*$','',trimmed)
lapply(lapply(strsplit(trimmed,'\\s*,\\s*'),unique),paste,sep =', ')
```

Comment: @Jthrope, I have a weird dataset for example the contents of my first cell is like this ` "Arizona, Arizona,Arizona "`

Comment: see edits, including trimming leading and trailing whitespace, and @Rick's edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a single `gsub` to get the unique values, but the order of elements will be different

```
df1$Result <- gsub('(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b.*), ', "",
         df1$State, perl=TRUE)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sN8pQ7/1)

```
df1$Result
#[1] "Arizona"                                                          
#[2] "California Carmel Beach, California LBC, California Napa, Arizona"
#[3] "Virginia"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(State = c("Arizona, Arizona, Arizona, Arizona", 
"Arizona, Arizona, Arizona, California Carmel Beach, California LBC, California Napa, Arizona", 
"Virginia, Virginia, Virginia")), .Names = "State", class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```